# pdf file generated using python pdfkit has no clickable links?

Tags: html, pdfkit, html-to-pdf

The html file looks like

```
        <div class="contact">
            Phone: +00-0000000<br/>
            E-mail: <a href="mailto:zsameem@gmail.com" >zsameem@gmail.com</a>
            Github: <a href="https://www.github.com/zsameem">www.github.com/zsameem</a>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

code for gennerating pdf is simply:

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_file('mypage.html', 'mypdf.pdf;')
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install wkhtmltopdf as described in the installing instructions? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit

That seems to be a point that is often missed when using pdfkit.